# What does 'rejected' mean for Deffered objects other than jqXHRs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, jqxhr

From `deferred.fail()` [page](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) :

> **Description**: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is
>   rejected.

and the exmple:

```
$.get("test.php")
.done(function(){ alert("$.get succeeded"); })
.fail(function(){ alert("$.get failed!"); });
```

As we know, we can create `var someObject = $.Deferred();`

My questions:

- How can we 'Reject' a Deferred if it's not a jqXHR?
- How to implement `deferred.fail()` for Deferred objects other than jqXHR?

Thanks.

Yes, I know my English is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deferred object is rejected when either [`.reject()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/) or [`.rejectWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.rejectWith/) is called on it.

Here's an example:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
deferred
  .done(function() { console.log('done') })
  .fail(function() { console.log('failed') });

deferred.resolve(); // <-- will write 'done' to console
deferred.reject();  // <-- will write 'failed' to console
```

You can use deferreds to make asynchronous functions behave like `$.get()` does. For example `setTimeout`:

```
function MyTimeout() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
    // as a demo, this will reject the deferred half the time
    if (Math.random() < 0.5)
      deferred.reject();
    else
      deferred.resolve();
  }, 2000);
  return deferred.promise();
}

MyTimeout()
  .done(function() { console.log('done') })
  .fail(function() { console.log('failed') });
```

The last statement can also be written as:

```
MyTimeout().then(
  function() { console.log('done') },
  function() { console.log('failed') }
);
```